# Strategy is not taking a lot of orders

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, algorithmic-trading

I am wanting this strategy to take more than 2 trades. If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

[Here is the trade log of the detailed trades it took (pricepoints etc)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN4Ed.png)

```
t = ticker.new(syminfo.prefix ,syminfo.tickerid, session.regular)
PDC = request.security(t, "D", close[1]) 
CDO = request.security(t, "D", open)
shortconditiontwo = close < CDO
shortcondition = isGapUp
sellconditiongapup = CDO - 1.00

if shortcondition and shortconditiontwo
    strategy.entry("gapup", strategy.long)
if close == sellconditiongapup
    strategy.close("gapup")
```

I tried reading the documentation and looking for multiple ways to retrieve the open of day, I was wondering if maybe I wasn't properly using the functions to retrieve the open of day. However I still can't get more than 2 trades.